# Simple python web server doesn't execute CGI scripts

Tags: permissions, python

I set up a python web server by opening a terminal in a directory and doing

```
python -m CGIHTTPServer
```

There is a CGI script in the directory but when I type into the browser

```
localhost:8000/script.cgi
```

The CGI script is not executed but is downloaded instead. I chmod'ed the script to 755 but still the same.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

From [its documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/cgihttpserver.html#module-CGIHTTPServer):

> The class will however, run the CGI script, instead of serving it as a file, if it guesses it to be a CGI script. **Only directory-based CGI are used — the other common server configuration is to treat special extensions as denoting CGI scripts.**
>
> The `do_GET()` and `do_HEAD()` functions are modified to run CGI scripts and serve the output, instead of serving files, if the request leads to somewhere below the `cgi_directories` path. [...]
>
> **`cgi_directories`**:
>       This defaults to `['/cgi-bin', '/htbin']` and describes **directories to treat as containing CGI scripts.**